# Opening a webpage in an Android App

Tags: java, android, html

I was wondering what you guys/gals would recommend in terms of opening a webpage inside an app (i.e a smaller window with a webpage open in it but not a web browser) Im trying to integrate my webpage into my app more or less. Thanks :)

Comment: google is not helping

Comment: guys hes talking about libGDX. Thats why google isnt helping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) layout?

In your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Include the `INTERNET` permission into your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And then in your Activity:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

This will embed a web-browser into your application (rather than open an external browser).

Comment: Thanks, I got off last night due to a downvote and it was getting late, this is exactly what I need if it works, I'll get back to you if it does and accept your answer!

Comment: how to open a web page in my application ??
Actually its asking me to choose installed application to open a web page. That i don't want.

Answer (score 2):

You can place you view group and then place the webview inside and modify size as needed

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your manifest file give the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

then you get the object from code

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```